# typescript calling function results with undefined

Tags: typescript

Having an issue with regard to calling the function in typescript

I have a class

```
 export class Test{
     constructor(){}

     public func1(req:request,res:Response) {
 // call method
        let func2 =  this.Func2();

     }

     private Func2():string{
       return "Hello";
   }
}
export default new Test();
```

I have an express Router class

```
import {Router} from "express";
import Test from '../Handlers/Test';
export class UserRouter {

router: Router;

constructor() {
    this.router = Router();

}

Routes() {
    this.router.route('/user').post(Test.Func1);
    return this.router;
}

}

export default new UserRouter().Routes();
```

The issue is when I try to call the method Func2 using this.Func2() in Func1() method i get an error stating cannot call Func2 of undefined. I either have to call it in 2 ways

1) `new Test().Func2() inside Func1() method as

```
public Func1(req:request,res:Response){
   let func2 = new Test().Func2();
}
```

2) make `Func2()` as static and then call it using `Test.Func2()`

```
public Func1(req:request,res:Response){
   let func2 = Test.Func2();
}

private static Func2():string{
   return "Hello";
}
```

why can't I just call it using `this.Func2()` ?

Is it because I am exporting new of Test() to the router method and that object is no longer in memory?

Comment: If `Func2` is static then it doesn't exist on `this`, only on `Test`.

Comment: @NitzanTomer that is correct, I can access it by making it static and calling it using Test.Func2 . My issue is that I am unable to call it using this.Func2() . I am able to also call it using new Test().Func2()

Comment: I can't say that I understand your problem.  Can you please edit your question and add a clear example that reproduces your problem?

Comment: @NitzanTomer I have edited the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is this:

```
this.router.route('/user').post(Test.Func1);
```

You are passing `Test.Func1` to be invoked later as a callback, when that function is finally invoked the scope of `this` won't be the instance (`Test`) but something else, and so you have two options:

(1) Bind it:

```
this.router.route('/user').post(Test.Func1.bind(Test));
```

(2) Arrow function:

```
this.router.route('/user').post(() => Test.Func1());
```

Answer (score 1):

**1)** `new Test().Func2()`

This will not work in Typescript level, because your method is private, so it is not accessible from the outside.

**2)** `Test.Func2()`

This will keep the function inside the `Test` itself, so the function will not been attached to any object ( `this` ).

**What about your code?**

Your code is working. Is this the same code you have tried?

```js
 class Test{
     constructor(){}

     func1(req,res) {
        let func2 =  this.func2();
        console.log(func2);
     }

     func2(){
       return "Hello";
   }
}

const t = new Test();
t.func1();
```

Comment: I am not trying to access Func 2 from outside. basically my Test class is imported into  a router class. When a certain api call is made, I am routing it to Test.func1. In Func 1 i am trying to the private method of func 2

Comment: Your code is working. Error is another place of your code.

Comment: @Suren Srapyan - In above code sample, If I call func2 without this keyword. it will not work.What would be the reason?.

Comment: because this is a method, it is bound to the object So you are telling for each object I call it, it binds `this` to that object

Comment: @SurenSrapyan I have edited my question. I have included the routes file as well. Is there an issue in the way I am exporting my class to the router file?